# Manipulate NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

Can anyone help me? This is my code:

```
f[x_ ] = x Exp[I z]] (Cos[z]] BesselJ[l, a *x] - BesselY[l, a *x] Sin[z])
u=0.1
v=6
```

on the other hand hand:

```
s2 = ParametricNDSolve[{(a^2 - (l (l + 1))/x^2 + E^(-(x/b))/x) g[x] + g''[x] == 0, g[u] == 1, g'[u] == (l + 1)/u}, g, {x, u, v}, {a, b, l}]
```

In the above two equations a,b and l are free parameters. I want to find z for different values of these free parameters. I want to manipulate these three parameters and see how z behaves under their variations. This is my code:

```
NSolve[(v f'[v]/f[v]) - 1 == v ( (D[Evaluate[g[a, b, l][x] /. s2], x] /. x -> v) / Evaluate[g[a, b, l][v] /. s2]) - 1 && 0 <=  z <=  \[Pi] , z]
```

The first problem is that NSolve can not solve the parametric equation. I do not know what code I should use. The second problem is when I manipulate the parameters, nothing happens:

```
Manipulate[NSolve[(v \f'[v]/f[v]) - 1 ==  v ( (D[Evaluate[g[a, b, l][x]. s2], x] /. x -> v) / Evaluate[g[a, b, l][v] /. s2]) - 1 && 0 <=  z <=\[Pi] , z], {a, .001, 10, 0.00001}, {b,0.1,1000,0.00001}, {l, 0, 1000, 1}]
```

Nothing happens. Or maybe the correct one is this code:

```
NSolve[Manipulate[(v \f'[v]/f[v]) - 1 ==  v ( (D[Evaluate[g[a, b, l][x]. s2], x] /. x -> v) / Evaluate[g[a, b, l][v] /. s2]) - 1, {a, .001, 10, 0.00001}, {b,0.1,1000,0.00001}, {l, 0, 1000, 1}] && 0 <=  z <=\[Pi] , z],
```

Again, nothing happens.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please correct `f[x_] := x Exp[I z] (Cos[z]  BesselJ[l, a*x] - BesselY[l, a*x] Sin[z])`.   `NSolve` can't evaluate because of undefined parameters `a,b,l`!

Answer (score 1):

Try (f[x] modified)

```
f[x_] := x Exp[I z] (Cos[z]  BesselJ[l, a*x] - BesselY[l, a*x] Sin[z])
u = 0.1
v = 6
```

solution of the ode

```
G = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(a^2 - (l (l + 1))/x^2 + E^(-(x/b))/x) g[x] + g''[x] == 0, g[u] == 1, g'[u] == (l + 1)/u},g, {x, u, v}, {a, b, l}]
```

`G[a,b,l][x]` is the parametric solution.

If I understand your `NSolve`right you try to solve `f[v]== G[a, b, l][v]`

```
sol[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ] :=NSolve[{6 E^(I z) (BesselJ[l, 6 a] Cos[z] - BesselY[l, 6 a] Sin[z]) ==G[a, b, l][v], 0 <= z <= Pi}, z, Reals]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I want to solve f'[v]/f[v]==G'[a,b,l][v]/G[a,b,l][v].  This is the error I get when I want to find sol[1,2,1]:  ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable g.

Comment: Please show your code! `f'[v]/f[v]==G'[a,b,l][v]/G[a,b,l][v]` is wrong, try `f'[v]/f[v]==G[a,b,l]'[v]/G[a,b,l][v]` instead.

Comment: I copied the above codes, everything is OK. But, when I want to test to see what will be z for different values of a, b and l, it does not give me the answer. This is the code:    'sol[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ] := 
 NSolve[{f'[v]/f[v] == G[a, b, l]'[v]/G[a, b, l][v], 0 <= z <= Pi}, z]' .  Now, I want to see what is z for a=1, b=2, l=1. I write this code f[1,2,1], but it does not give me any answe.